# "sh: no closing quote" When trying to make an ASCII echo convert script

Tags: python, escaping

I'm trying to convert an ASCII art file to an echo command which can run it without any errors, I'm getting an error when it tries to run the script at the last line, the error is:

```sh
sh: no closing quote
```

I probably made my script the wrong way, how would I fix it?

The script:

```py
import sys, os

text = sys.stdin.read()
full = "echo -e \""
chars_to_escape = ["!",'"',"#","$","&","'","(",")","*",";","<",">","?",

for char in text:
    if char in chars_to_escape:
        full += f"\"\{char}\""
    else:
        full += char

print(full)
os.system(full)
```

The ASCII art:

```
,--.
                          {    }
                          K,   }
                         /  `Y`
                    _   /   /
                   {_'-K.__/
                     `/-.__L._
                     /  ' /`\_}
                    /  ' /
            ____   /  ' /
     ,-'~~~~    ~~/  ' /_
   ,'             ``~~~%%',
  (                     %  Y
 {                      %% I
{      -                 %  `.
|       ',                %  )
|        |   ,..__      __. Y
|    .,_./  Y ' / ^Y   J   )|
\           |' /   |   |   ||
 \          L_/    . _ (_,.'(
  \,   ,      ^^""' / |      )
    \_  \          /,L]     /
      '-_`-,       ` `   ./`
         `-(_            )
             ^^\..___,.--`
```

Comment: char_to_escape array is not closed : typo ?

Comment: Incidentally, if you’re targeting POSIX sh or Bash (or most other related shells), the `chars_to_escape` list is wrong, most of these characters do *not* need to be escaped in double quotes (of the listed characters, only `$` and `"` require escaping), and you forgot some (notably \\).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add the last quote to the `full` variable.